# what is the best way of passing unknown number of strings to a function in java

Tags: java, string

I want to pass a diffrent number of strings to a function in java, it suppose to be the strings to filter a query by, it could be 2-4 strings.

What do you think will be the best way to do that?

a) creating an overload for the same function with different number of parameters?
b) create a new instance of an array of string and pass it to the function?

any other preffered way?

thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Java has supported variable argument lists since [1.5](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/language/varargs.html):

```
public void myMethod(String... values)
{
    for (String val : values)
    {
        // do something
    }
}
```

The rules are simple:

- The variable argument must be the last argument in the method signature.
- It's a single argument, so all values will be of the same type.
- Inside the method, the vararg appears to be an array.
- When calling the method, you can either pass individual values or an array.

Comment: Great, thanks! Do you need to pass at least one parameter or there is a chance the array will be empty?

Comment: @Doron - no, you'll get an empty array if you don't pass any arguments.

Comment: If you want to ensure that the no-argument version is never called, you could use the following signature: `public void myMethod(String value, String... values)` then process value before processing values.

Answer (score 0):

Creating an overload (a) has the advantage that you'll get a compile-time error if you pass wrong number of strings.

Alternatively you can use [varargs](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/varargs.html).

Comment: Don't you think it will be a waste of code, writing the same function 3 times?

Comment: @Doron Sinai: Two of them can be made trivial, e.g. passing nulls instead of the missing arguments. This is similar to the telescopic constructor pattern which has its advantages and disadvantages.

Answer (score 0):

You can go for `varargs`.
http://www.developer.com/java/other/article.php/3323661